# Google Maps API - How to Send CORS Request for Place Photo

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cors

I'm using the following code to get photo reference from the `places_changed` event of the autocomplete object.

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();        
    var ref = place.reference;
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference="+ref;
});
```

So how would I make a HTTP request to `url`. Using `$.getJSON()` is resulting in CORS issue. Is there any other way I can overcome this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with the response(assuming it would work, the response will be an image)

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting an image in response. I'd then insert that image onto my page so that I'll have the textual address and its corresponding image side by side

Comment: create a `<img/>`-element, set the `src`-attribute to `url` and place it where you want to  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: Oh man, how silly of me. I don't know why I didn't think of that. But I ran into another issue now - The image being returned is the one which appears when the quota has been reached. I'm sure that I couldn't have made more than 8-10 requests in the last 30 minutes. Is the quota limit that low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `<img/>`-element, set the src-attribute to `url` and place it where you want to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Related to the quota-issue: You are loading the photo via the webservice( https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/photos ) , a key is required there.

When you use the places-library of the maps-Javascript-API retrieve the URL of the photo via `getUrl()`and you'll be able to load the photo without a key:

```js
function init() {
  var image = new Image(),
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (place.photos && place.photos.length) {
      input.style.background = '#fff';
      image.src = place.photos[0].getUrl({
        maxwidth: 200,
        maxHeight: 150
      });
      document.body.appendChild(image);

    } else {
      input.style.background = 'tomato';
      if (image.parentNode) {
        image.parentNode.removeChild(image)
      }
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<input/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>

        <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

        <div id="mapholder"></div>
        <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

            var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
            +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
            document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
        }

        function showError(error) {
            switch(error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }
        </script>
```

try this code...

Comment: Where do I call these functions `getLocation()` and `showPosition()` ? Inside the `places_changed` event?

Comment: <p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>

          <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

           <div id="mapholder"></div>

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that I'm looking for something like that